# How to turn a pandas Series to a seaborn bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, data-science

I have a Pandas Series I created from answers to survey questions. For example

```
Age      q1       
10+      No           16
         No Answer     1
         Yes           8
5-7      No           20
         No Answer     1
         Yes          22
7-9      No           18
         No Answer     1
         Yes          16
Under 5  No           11
```

Now I want to create a seaborn bar chart for this. In the bar chart I want the 'Age' to be x axis and each Age bucket should show the count for each answer in a different color as shown in here.

[seaborn bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KF4H.png)

Comment: `df.unstack().plot(kind='bar')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

sns.set(style="white", context="talk")

d1 =['Age','q1','q2']  #have taken count as q2
data= [
        ['10+','No',16],
        ['10+','No Answer',1],
        ['10+','Yes',8],
        ['5-7','No',20],
        ['5-7','No Answer',1],
        ['5-7','Yes',22],
        ['7-9','No',18],
        ['7-9','No Answer',1],
        ['7-9','Yes',16],
        ['Under5','No',11,]
       ]

df =pd.DataFrame(data,columns=d1)

sns.catplot(x="Age", y="q2", hue="q1", data=df,
                height=6, kind="bar", palette="muted")

plt.show()
```

[image]